# Hide TextArea when convert to Ms word

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, css

Suppose that I have the php code as below:

```
<form method="post" action="htmltortf.php">
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>Candidate Name:</td>
                <td colspan="3"><textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="textArea"><?php echo $var = isset($_POST['textArea']) ? $_POST['textArea'] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {                   
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2doc.doc");
        }
?>
```

**What I need:**

I want that when the user click on button submit, it will generate to Ms word but for the textArea I do not want it to display the style of it like border or... I just want to display only the value of it.eg:`This is the textArea in the Ms word file`.

**The Problem:**

When I convert it, it still show the style of textArea like border and scroll...

I do not know how to fix this?Anyone help me please,

Thanks.

Comment: i don't see the code where you create the word file.

Comment: your outputting headers claiming you have a word document, that does not mean you have a valid word document. you cant convert html to word by changing  the file name.

Comment: Yes sure I just change the file name.So how do I fix this?

Comment: you have asked this several times before and been answered.

Comment: this same question is here http://jisku.com/blog/2012/09/hide-textarea-when-convert-to-ms-word/

Comment: I don understand.It is not have the solution yet.

Comment: here is a tip, the actual question is "how do I create a word document with the output of a form"

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not creating a valid Word (.doc) document - it will still work as a normal word file when downloaded.

The solution to your problem:

```
<form method="post" action="htmltortf.php">
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Candidate Name:</td>
         <td colspan="3">
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>
<?php echo $_POST['textArea']; // echo just the posted value ?>
<?php else: // or show textarea field ?>
             <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="textArea"><?php echo $var = isset($_POST['textArea']) ? $_POST['textArea'] : ''; ?></textarea>
<?php endif ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{                   
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=html2doc.doc");
}
?>
```

I assume you are aware of users being able to post HTML code in textarea which may result in malformed DOC output so you should probably use `strip_tags()` or `htmlspecialchars()` on `$_POST['textArea']` before echoing it.